# Convert 2D array string elements to int using parseInt

Tags: javascript

I am not able to convert string 2D **elements** to `int`. I have been using `parseInt` in javascript. But it gives me an **error**.

I have tried using `ParseInt`.

```
$.get('LSDE/inOutDegrees/2011.csv', function parseInt(data) {

    var result = $.csv.toArrays(data)
    var x = [[0,1],[1,3]]

    console.log(x,data.length)

    var list = []

    for(var i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(list[i] == null){
            list.push(result[i])
        }
    }

    for(var j=0;j<=1;j++)
    {
        console.log(parseInt(list[j][0])
    }
```

I expected it parse the values to `int` but it gave me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: did you try to print out (console.log) `list` before iterating on it ?

Comment: I did that and it worked fine. The only problem is the above error. I got the expected output for logging the "list" object

Comment: you're missing a closing paren in the console log. why aren't you getting a syntax error?

Comment: Fine. this have happened when I was pasting the code.

Comment: Hi @srinivas muralidharan, Could you provide me with a sample of your data?

Comment: @ppotaczek, Sorry man, its kind of confidential. Rather I can get you a sample data of my own creation? a similar one though?

Comment: Sure, it's mainly about data structure.

Comment: yes sure. I will get it asap

Comment: `$.get('LSDE/inOutDegrees/2011.csv', function parseInt(data) {`  here why `parseInt`. Just use normal anonymous function ??